# Making phone number sharing optional in google sign in integration using gapi

Tags: javascript, authentication, google-api, google-authentication, google-api-js-client

I am trying to integrate google `SignIn` on our webpage, would like to get user phone number while signing in, as an optional property. So that if the user did not want to share their phone number while signing they should be able to skip and continue with `SignIn`.

As of now when users click `cancel` on the `permission window for accessing phone number` user is not getting signed in.

Following is the code sample used for doing google sign in, and to access user phone number,

```
gapi.auth.signIn({
  cookiepolicy: "single_host_origin",
  clientid: "googleAppClientID",
  fetch_basic_profile: false,
  scope: "email profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.phonenumbers.read",
  callback: "googleSignInCallback"
});
```

This opens up a popup after email authentication, to allow access for my app to read the user phone number.

[image]

When the user clicks `Cancel` on this screen, the user is not getting logged in.

Is it possible to make this a nonmandatory for users, so that they can skip or not share the phone number?

Comment: Maybe you could further request for the phone number scope on the feature that requires that scope? Like a button which when clicked will request for the additional scope. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/incremental-auth for more info on how to request for additional scopes.

Comment: I was trying to access the phone number as part of login flow, at the same time it is not mandatory as well for users to access the logged-in session. Yes, as you mentioned in the system where the user is trying to access some particular pages we are accessing the phone number as mandatory information. Now we are trying to access the phone number as part of login flow as non--mandatory information.